# Strange pictures

Tags: lateral-thinking, visual

Here's a little puzzle I threw together in honor of today. What are the pictures trying to say?

(Note: It's my first time posting here, so I'm bad at formatting, and can't figure out how to resize pictures. The caption for each image is above the image.)

(6,2)

[image: 6, 2]

---

(5, 5)

[image: 5, 5]

---

(7, 3)

[image: 7, 3]

---

(4, 2)

[image: 4, 2]

---

(11, 4)

[image: 11, 4]

---

(6, 1)

[image: 6, 1]

---

(6, 6)

[image: 6, 6]

Hint:

> The numbers are the length of the clue for the picture and the index of the key letter.

Comment: "in honor [US spelling] of today" - I guess this is something to do with Independence Day?

Comment: @randal'thor maaaaaybe. ;) Though to be honest the solutions to these pictures aren't quite the country's proudest moments in my opinion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pictures refer to unusual celebrity baby names.

*Blue Ivy* C**a**rter

*Moon Unit* Zapp**a**

*Blanket* Ja**c**kson

*North* W**e**st

*Briar Rose* Chr**i**stensen (thanks to M Oehm)

*Apple* **M**artin (thanks to rand al'thor)

*Summer Rain* Rutle**r** (thanks to M Oehm)

As Bravo noted, the selected letters anagram to **America**.

Comment: [This](http://www.cracked.com/article_15765_the-20-most-bizarre-celebrity-baby-names.html) might be useful. Apple Martin?

Comment: Also, you need an extra ? to make 7 in total ... and I think it's now obvious what the answer's going to be ;-)

Comment: Prince Michael II's nickname was 'blanket.' Princess could maybe be Princess Tiaamii?

Comment: @Demesne Nope, we need 11 letters for the Princess surname...

Comment: Haha wow you're good! The last two are definitely the hardest, though. Here's a hint for you: Identify the specific princess! Maybe she has several names?

Comment: Very good! The fifth seems to be Briar Rose Christensen. (That's what google tells me, I knew neither the name Briar Rose for the fairy tale nor the celebrity in question.)

Comment: @MOehm Briar Rose is the nickname given to Princess Aurora (Sleeping Beauty) in the picture. It also refers to the folktale "Little Briar Rose," which was used as the basis for the Disney film.

Comment: The last could be Esmeralda Amanda... relating esmeralda to emerald color? Anyway the final answer is AMERICA after anagramming...

Comment: @mmking: The German name for both folk tale and princess is _Dornröschen_ (thorny rose), but I thought that the tale was called "Sleepig Beauty" in English, so the name Briar Rose was new to me.

Comment: @Bravo: So the last letter should be an R. Summer Rain Rutler, Christina Aguilera's daughter, seems a better fit.

Comment: You got it! Happy fourth, guys.

Answer (score 0):

The first image shows ivy, which could be a reference to the US Ivy League of universities. Let's say the keyword is LEAGUE, making the key letter **E**.

The second image shows a lunar rover. The keyword is ROVER and the key letter **R**.

The third image shows a BLANKET, with key letter **A**.

The fourth image shows a compass ROSE, with key letter **O**.

The fifth image shows a Disney princess? Not sure about an 11-letter word.

The sixth image shows an apple? Not sure about a 6-letter word.

The seventh image shows rain on a WINDOW, with key letter **W**.

Rearranging the letters, we could get something to do with WAR. The US is certainly a war-mongering nation, and this could fit the OP's comment about "not quite the country's proudest moments".

Comment: That's Princess Aurora from Sleeping Beauty. Not sure about the 11 letter word either though.